# How can I reduce duplication of radio buttons?

Tags: forms, input-fields, radio-buttons

I've been asked to redesign a score calculator for a website. At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to optimise the radio inputs, so that there isn't as much repetition?

I considered placing the labels (pass, merit, distinction) as column headings, but perhaps as users work down through the form they might forget what each input corresponds to?

**update**

For clarification, the scoring system is complex and not something I have control over. As pointed out by Andrew Martin in the comments below, it does appear that the Grade should derive from the score. Unfortunately it doesn't work that way, and I agree that it's not very intuitive.

Comment: Why do you think repetition is a bad thing? Have you asked the users if they find the radio button repetition a bad thing?

Comment: Wouldn't the level of pass (Pass, Merit, Distinction) be derived from the score? Surely that part could be automated?

Comment: @AndrewMartin Unfortunately not, the score refers to how the class is weighted (It's a complex system... ). While the level is the actual grade.

Comment: @SteveD I guess I assumed it was cumbersome, and it just looked a bit busy for me. We have limited feedback so far, but no complaints

Comment: @ovokuro You could use drop down fields to reduce visual impact (which would increase interaction cost) although you would still need the repetition.

Comment: I wonder if the use of visual design could solve the heavy look? Maybe adding a little breathing room and some grays to offset the odd rows? Usually in this case, you can't really get away from repetition, only because these values are necessary to move forward. You could do a multistep process, but that will make the process too cumbersome when it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @Majo0od I think this might be the best approach.

Comment: Whatever design you come up with, make sure that you minimize the number of keystrokes required to enter the data. Also, make sure that the total number of keystrokes does not depend on the value that is entered. From my experience with very similar forms containing student data, being able to navigate forms by using combinations of <TAB> and <SPACE> *without having to look at the screen* is extremely important.

Comment: *Just read these comments after posting my answer* ... How can a score not correlate to a grade? Just because the ranges are configurable doesn't mean the system can't understand them. It just needs to know about the decisions that have been made.

Comment: "I've been asked to redesign a score calculator for a website" sounds like somebody has a reason for wanting this particular page redesigned. Have you spoken to them about what is currently causing them pain?

Comment: Should it work on mobile?

Comment: @Runnick Yes it will need to work on all screen sizes

Comment: *How can a score not correlate to a grade?* Historically, marking of mathematics papers at certain top universities once had this feature. One could give correct but plodding answers to enough questions and score 100% yet still only be rated upper second class. To get a first you needed to display some mathematical brilliance and have sufficient answers rated alpha. An alpha could reputedly be awarded for an incomplete answer or for an erroneous one if the error was trivially fix-able.

Comment: @nigel222 As I've stated multiple times in the comments and in the question update, the score does not correlate. The score relates to how a class is weighted (as in, how many credits its worth). The terminology is admittedly awkward but that's the system we're working with where I'm from. I never asked for a redesign of the scoring system, just the radio buttons. Apologies for any confusion, I thought one explanatory comment would suffice.

Comment: I'd be perfectly happy with this as an interface. If it was guaranteed that the number of classes could never exceed the reasonably available screen height I'd move "Pass" "Merit" "Distinction" to the top line. If vertical scrolling might be needed in some cases, the repetition is actually better.

Comment: @nigel222 Good point. On mobile the height might be an issue, but then the repetition would take up more space...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Actually, there could be a way to make this a tad bit less heavy.

In your situation, you're repeating words which are not absolutely necessary. Try something like this in addition to adding more breathing space + visual design to make it easier on the eye. The problem with the wireframing tool, we aren't able to choose different colors to make options softer on the eyes:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1rxZd.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Make sure the header is sticky to the top so that the labels are always visible.

Comment: I like this a lot. I think the division between the rows breaks it up well, and as you say adding colour will help further.

Comment: I like this a lot. Some people have said that maybe the users will forget the column names as they go down the rows, I think this is wrong. There is a clear informational hierarchy, with the options being better as you go towards the right hand side, as well as the users being presumably already familiar with the grading system being used.

Comment: @Rugnir you could also make the header sticky (which is what I suggest)

Comment: this solution actually takes into account the effort required to fill out the form, unlike a lot of the other answers. Also, this solution uses common patterns in ways that a lot of users will expect them to be used.

Comment: This design (like the original) assumes that one of pass, merit, or distinction *must* be awarded. What if somebody failed? Deselecting a mis-clicked radio button is… tricky (maybe why they're asking for the redesign in the first place?)

Comment: I like the header-up idea, but I wouldn't add coloumn separators to the design, as each row will be essentially the same it is already easy enough to distinguish coloumns of data. Row separators are OK though.

Comment: To be honest i personally would've preffered a triple-button-bar widget instead of radio buttons, especially without big text label they are a pain to click, unlike buttons.

Comment: @Dave from what I gathered, a selection has to be made, so a radio button is the right way to go. If they miss-click, then they can click something else?

Comment: Plus, the goal was to make this less heavy, not to completely redesign everything.

Comment: @Majo0od a quick visual redesign is what the OP interpreted the request to be, but I suspect there were more practical concerns behind the actual request, and the requester will be left disappointed. I'd be very surprised if fails are impossible in a grading system, hence why I think that's likely to be their primary existing issue with it. OP needs to talk to their customer more.

Comment: @Dave A fail is simply not entered into the calculator. It's not an issue. My interpretation of the request is correct thanks

Comment: Radio buttons without a label are very hard to click though.

Comment: @svenmeier not really... You can make the hit area bigger, or just enlarge the radio buttons. So many ways to make them not hard to click.

Comment: @Majo0od yes, enlarging the click area to the whole cell would definitely help.

Comment: “Some people have said that maybe the users will forget the column names as they go down the rows, I think this is wrong.” If only there were some way to try this form out on real people, and see if that happens.

Answer (score 44):

## The secret sauce of product design

You mentioned that the score and rank are determined independently. This sounds to me like a classic example of **the feature no one asked for but everyone wanted.**

The test designer must have a system in their mind for how score and rank relate — obtuse though it may seem. Dig deeper and see if there isn't a feature opportunity hidden in this problem somewhere.

If there's a score, there's a potential total. I can only assume the workflow:

1. Set up a "test" with data on the total for each "class"
2. Optionally customize the scale for pass / merit / distinction
3. Fills out a form for each evaluation against this known test

## Let the system do the thinking

The system should be aware that score `n` equates rank `x`. Don't make the user do two things when they can just do one: Enter a simple number and *voila* — rank is calculated!

This also eliminates a potential point of human error.

[image: Examples of score input with system-generated classification]

A few notes about the example:

- Icons are friendly
- Good / Outstanding sounds more natural than Merit / Distinction
- You can reinforce the potential total or allow configuration inline

## Worst case scenario

If the system is ignorant to all of that, just make the user's actions as obvious as possible. Then watch them in action and make sure that ignorance is justified.

[image: Classification selector as text-based toggle]

Comment: I believe toggle buttons are the best option. Made **[a sketch](https://i.imgur.com/Ti8m7az.png)** to check, but it doesn't solve the main concern about reducing the amount of elements (or text labels at least). But contrary to radio buttons I think it is more clear the button can be deselected (if this is necessary for the scenario).

Comment: @plainclothes Thanks for answer. Unfortunately, as mentioned in the question, the score and grade are not related as one would assume, therefore the grade can not be determined from the score.

Comment: @plainclothes I think the last option is good, I'm not sure about placing the labels 'Class 1' above the box though. I find it slightly harder to scan, but that might just be me

Comment: Since it should be working on mobile, I'm voting this. Though I don't like  small arrows on number inputs.

Comment: @Runnick I have to agree with you on the small arrows. That's the standard "number field" indicator in my wireframe components, but they are annoyingly small.

Comment: I liked your answer, but what's with the emoji?

Comment: @oldmud0 it's all about the ✨

Comment: All I see is a little box where the emoji should be. It shows fine in your comment though (3 little stars, right?)

Answer (score 33):

Slight modification of DesignerAnalyst's solution:

[image: Star rating]

- star ratings are commonly used and known
- allows no preselection
- in contrast to sliders there are exact three allowed states
- no header required, each label changes immediately conveying the meaning of the stars before it

Comment: You can certainly make a slider have 3 exact states. People do this all the time for surveys.

Comment: I like this solution over the sliders because it's clear that there are only 3 choices.

Comment: How will a user know what the stars represent before clicking them?

Comment: I would argue that stars are not as heavily used only because they've become so cumbersome to deal with. My BIGGEST problem with this is that you're equating the values of the star with the selection when in fact it might not be the case. Are you saying "Distinction" is FAR better than pass? That doesn't seem to be the case here...

Comment: Problem with these sort of suggestions is that it seems like you're rating grades when you are not.

Comment: When you hover over a star, it could already reveal its meaning. Obsviously this is not suitable for a touch device.

Comment: @Seiyria While a slider _can_ have (a small number of) discrete states, (a) most implementations I've seen that do this feel "clunky" (doesn't mean it couldn't be done well, but they tend not to be from my experience), and (b) again to me, a slider implies an _analogue_ (continuously variable) selection, not discrete steps (which is probably why I find them clunky). (Obviously even a "continuously variable" slider will have discrete steps, but they are normally very small and it _appears_ continuous).

Answer (score 12):

A visual idea of what has been told until now:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQjTRA.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

However using combo boxes requires (for some) two clicks opposed to one click for radio buttons. Should you prefer the latter, go for floating headers.

Comment: This might have solved the problem of making it "less heavy" but the user experience has been impacted greatly (now instead of clicking once per class to assigned a type value, you have to click 2 - 3 times to get to what was previously a click away).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I agree that this looks neater, but as @Majo0od points out it might be slower for users, especially on mobile. It might be worth testing out though

Comment: @Majo0od - agreed. Fortunately, there is a better answer already.

Comment: @Majo0od I somewhat disagree with a keyboard this becomes the fastest one, Combine with a power user using a keyboard it becomes 57 tab key P tab key..... 7 tab key M  tab key ....etc. Definitely the fastest way compared to the others

Comment: @Halfwarr In this day in age when you're designing for *only* keyboard on desktop, you'll get in trouble, especially when you're sacrificing the mobile experience...

Comment: But also you have to take in account how many people are going to use this in mobile, vs how many using this on desktop vs how many only keyboard.

Comment: @Majo0od If we are considering mobile I would think  a box with a drop-down would be the best option though vs a bunch of radio buttons just based on the ammount of screen real estate used

Comment: You should reconsider that @Halfwarr.... http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1950

Comment: But I don't think this interface would be for mobile (since OP hasn't said it would be)

Comment: Had to join this site just to upvote this answer. I find drop down menus like this FAR easier to use, even on mobile, when done correctly. I don't have to move my mouse/finger as far to get to the options, and the extra screen real estate allows for large, easily clickable boxes instead of smaller radio buttons. I feel that the time saved by less hand movement and larger objects to click on makes up for the extra click.

Answer (score 12):

The problem I have with so many radio buttons is their low signal to noise ratio: the state is expressed by the presence or absence of little dot inside a tiny circle (next to some text). Having the text repeated on several rows only worsens the impression and can make one feel lost in an endless field.

Simply restyling the radio buttons, so that more pixels contribute to the visualization of their state can improve things.

[image: Background color specifies radio button's state]

My suggestion is to have the selected radio buttons show with different background.

Second line of defense that can reduce cluter is to make not selected buttons have either dimmed or invisible text on them:

- They could be dimmed on undecided rows or on the row under the mouse.
- Conversely they could be invisible on rows that are both decided and not under the mouse.

Removing some unnecessary vertical stems might also help.

Comment: I think this is actually heavier than the OP's design.

Answer (score 3):

Usually interfaces are overloaded with words, which makes interfaces more difficult and efforful for users. I recommend a wordless solution. you may try a three state slider or a custom three state graphic control :

[image: mockup]

**EDIT:**

The wordless solution by Majo0od (without the grid lines) is much better than the two recommendations above. I will keep them though just for discussion.

Comment: +1 - if I was to improve my answer, I'd do it this way. One remark - I would put clear tick stops on the sliders.

Comment: Interesting solution. I hadn't considered a slider. Is this any better than having 3 radio buttons and headings at the top though? Also wondering how this will feel on mobile. Lastly, a slider will be required to have a default value set, whereas a radio button won't. Thanks for answer

Comment: I'm already shuddering at how awkward this would be to actually use. Sure, it looks much better, but dragging that slider is going to be painful, and even with checkmarks I suspect that clicking on the slider isn't going to be as precise or as discoverable as clicking radio buttons.

Comment: I'm incredibly worried by the second option. Out of curiosity, is "pass" equal to 33% of the grade? Actually, in both options it actually appears that way.

Comment: Sliders are not a good equivalent for something that is a set of distinct choices.  It's not at all clear that the slider represents 3 choices rather than a sliding 0-100% scale.

Comment: The other problem here is that the user may think the slider/progress control is a reflection of the value entered for Grade rather than a separate input altogether.

Comment: Here's a quick demo of this solution >> http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/RVbxVB -- after moving a few sliders around it starts to get messy...

Answer (score 2):

I think that the column header solution is the correct choice.
But this produces a new problem, as you correctly stated: the user might forget those radio meaning.

Focusing only on this last problem, you could use a sticky header pattern.
So, as you scroll your content, the whole row containing labels should stick to the top, while the rows should scroll beneath it.

I hope i explained myself.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm not sure how beneficial making the header sticky would be as there are only 10 rows. Definitely a good idea if there were more rows though.

Comment: If this is for web or desktop application, you could consider to make an hint appear when hovering over the radio button.
The hint would show the radio label, making it obvious.

Comment: It's for a website, so an alternative to a hover effect will have to be considered for mobile users. Interesting idea, thanks